# merging two table on range based data

Tags: mysql

Having a table with employees data and a table for salary.
Trying to merge salary with employee table on basis of experience and position.

```
Employee Table

id| age | name | exp  | posi
_   _     __     ___    ____
1 |  10 |   A  |  1.1 | Jr
 _   _     __    ___   ____
2 |  25 |   B  |  3.1   | Sr
_   _     ____   __    ___
3 |  15 |   C  |  3.5   | Sr
_   ___    ___   ___    __
4 |  22 |   D  |  2.04  | Jr

Salary Table 

posi| exp_from| exp_to  |Salary
___   ________ _______    ___
Jr |      1   |  2      | 100
___   ________ _______    ___
Jr |      2   |  3     | 200
___   ________ _______    ___
Sr |      3   |  4      | 300
___   ________ _______    ___
Sr |      4   |  5      | 400


Tried Query = 
SELECT
   IFNULL(salary_table.salary,'not found') as salary,
   employee_table.*,
   FROM
   `employee_table` 
   LEFT JOIN
      salary_table
      ON employee_table.posi = salary_table.posi
      AND employee_table.exp >= salary_table.exp_from 
      AND employee_table.exp <= salary_table.exp_to
```

Issue :
1.Having data more than 50k some some rows getting wrong salary where exp is like 1.21 or 1.80

2.Due to large amount of data query takes like 2-3mints for execution in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Your question is not  clear  ?  what's your question ?  .. you have an error ?? show the exact error message ... wrong result  ??  add a proper data sample and the expected result. .. Better performance ??  add the tables schema and the query explain plan ..

Comment: Since exp_from and exp_to overlap, one of them should be excusive and the other inclusive. You can't use >= and <= for both. What is the salary for exp=2.0?

Answer (score 0):

```
select employee.id, employee.age, employee.name, employee.exp, employee.posi, salary.salary
from employee, salary
where employee.exp > salary.exp_from and employee.exp<= salary.exp_to;
```

RESULT:

> ```
> 1 10  A   1.1  Jr 100
> 4 22  D   2.04 Jr 200
> 2 25  B   3.1  sr 300
> 3 15  C   3.5  Sr 300
> ```